# jQuery template on complete render event

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

just curious if there is a way to trigger operation (or attach event to) once the `jQuery.template( name, template )` method completes the rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $.tmpl method executes synchronously as far as i can see. Why not just put the operation on the next line? "It won't run until the render is complete.